# Paypal auto login redirect

Tags: php, paypal

I want auto redirect to my website after sucessfull payment from PayPal.

Here is my code:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="jtest@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Item #1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Item #2">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="2.00">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost/thanks.php" />
<input type="submit" value="PayPal">
</form>
```

Note, 'localhost' is used just as a demonstration.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: it is not redirecting to my website back.

Comment: Have you tried with a value different from `localhost`?

Comment: I edited your question and added clarification regarding 'localhost' as per your comments. Please _double check my edit to ensure it is correct_ as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

To enable an automatic redirect, enable 'Auto Return' within 'Website Payment Preferences' of your PayPal Profile.
Note: This will only automatically redirect registered PayPal users. Guest buyers will still need to click on a 'Return to merchant' button in order to be redirected.

You can customize the text of this 'Return to merchant' button by passing in the 'cbt' variable: input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="My custom text" will rename the button the "My custom text".